# left_join on concordant and non-concordant data ifelse

Tags: r, dplyr, tidyverse

I am trying to do a `left_join` between `df1` and `df2` below, but **with a condition** (i.e., relatively similar to an ifelse statement).

```
dput(df1)
structure(list(variable1_a = c(2, 1, 1, 2, 1, 2), variable2_a = c(22, 
22, 23, 23, 25, 25), variable3 = c(0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1)), row.names = c(NA, 
-6L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"))
```

```
dput(df2)
structure(list(variable1_b = c(2, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2), variable2_b = c(22, 
23, 25, 22, 23, 25), outcome = c(100, 120, 140, 80, 20, 400)), row.names = c(NA, 
-6L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"))
```

The condition works as follows: when a dummy variable called `variable3` from `df1` equals 1 I want perform a regular left_join between `df1` and `df2` (i.e., `variable1_a` = `variable1_b` and `variable2_a` = `variable2_b`). However, when `variable3` from `df1` equals 0 I to perform a join between `df1` and `df2` such that `variable1_a` = `variable1_b` and `variable2_a` != `variable2_b`.

Put differently if `variable3` equals 1 I want to do a regular `left_join` but if it equals 0 I want to perform a join based on the condition that `variable1_a` = `variable1_b` but `variable2_a` != `variable2_b` (i.e., with all other values of `variable2_b`).

Does this make sense to anyone? I am happy to use other methods to perform this join.

Unfortunately, besides this I have not much code to show...

`df_final <- left_join(df1, df2, by = c(variable1_a, variable1_b, variable2_a, variable2_b)`

Thank you!

```
dput(df_final)
structure(list(variable1_a = c(2, 2, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 1, 2), variable2_a = c(22, 
22, 22, 22, 23, 23, 23, 25, 25), variable3 = c(0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 
0, 0, 1, 1), outcome = c(20, 400, 120, 140, 120, 100, 400, 140, 
400)), row.names = c(NA, -9L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"
))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way of doing it is to join on `variable1_a == variable1_b` and then filter according to `variable3` and your condition:

```
left_join(df1, df2, by = c("variable1_a" = "variable1_b")) %>%
  filter(
    (variable3 == 1 & variable2_a == variable2_b) |
    (variable3 == 0 & variable2_a != variable2_b)
  ) %>%
  select(-variable2_b)
```

Answer (score 1):

Another way would be to just 2-step the joins. Divide your dataframe into pieces, make the joins you want, then bind back together.

```
join1 <- df1 %>%
  filter(variable3 == 1) %>%
  left_join(df2, by = c('variable1_a' = 'variable1_b', 'variable2_a' = 'variable2_b'))

join2 <- df1 %>%
  filter(variable3 == 0) %>%
  left_join(df2, by = c('variable1_a' = 'variable1_b'), keep = TRUE) %>%
  filter(variable2_a != variable2_b) %>%
  select(-ends_with("b"))

final <- bind_rows(join1, join2)

# A tibble: 9 x 4
  variable1_a variable2_a variable3 outcome
        <dbl>       <dbl>     <dbl>   <dbl>
1           1          23         1     120
2           1          25         1     140
3           2          25         1     400
4           2          22         0      20
5           2          22         0     400
6           1          22         0     120
7           1          22         0     140
8           2          23         0     100
9           2          23         0     400
```